# Relation between bulk Hamiltonian in AdS and stress energy of CFT

Tags: gravity, conformal-field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, ads-cft

Consider the following two situations:

1. One can define a stress energy [for AdS](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9902121) which matches with the expectation value for the CFT stress tensor.
2. Consider bulk metric perturbations of the form:
   $$g_{\mu\nu} = g^{AdS}_{\mu \nu} + h_{\mu \nu}$$
   The boundary value of $h_{\mu\nu}$ sources the CFT stress tensor. However the gravity Hamiltonian can be written in the following form ([see this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.10154)):
   $$H = \lim_{\rho \to \pi/2} (cos\rho)^{2-d}\int d^{d-1}\Omega \dfrac{h_{00}}{16\pi G_N}$$
   where $\rho \to \pi/2$ denotes the boundary.

Here are my questions:

1. Is the gravity Hamiltonian the $00$th component of the AdS stress energy as defined in the paper above?
2. If that is so, isn't it contradictory that $00$th component of the AdS stress energy sources the CFT stress energy, resulting in the matching of the AdS stress energy with the expectation value of the CFT stress energy?